# NativeScript’s WebView play video inline

Tags: android, ios, webview, nativescript

Playing video inline in a WebView on NativeScript 3.4 & 4.0. This on both iOS and on Android.

I have this already [new-video-policies-for-ios](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/). What I am looking for is that I have do to to make it work in a WebView on iOS and Android with Nativescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is posted at github, [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/5726#issuecomment-383860590).

Answer (score 0):

your use video tag in html, this is example https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: Yes I already do. But I need also tell the NativeScript WebView to be able to play video inline without users interaction.

Comment: you use directive autoplay in video tag.

Comment: Yes. But it do not work without allowing your app to play this videos. And its here I am lost. I do not know how to tell my WebView to play this videos